# Jtable should accept only numbers

Tags: java, jtable

I want that in `jtable` only numbers should be accepted and I have used the properties of `jtable` and set the value of column to `integer` but after 10 digits it is not accepting numbers. So is there any way I can pply the validation of numbers without using `textfield` as I don't want to use it.

Comment: `Long` or `BigDecimal`/`BigInteger` would do. Or you use a textfield with pattern

Comment: How can we use textfield with pattern?